# Edit a string in C++ (Envoy)

Tags: c++, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I am trying to edit a string from Envoy (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/source/common/formatter/substitution_formatter.cc#L1068) but I when I test the build with my changes the code is compiled but I got the following error:

Warning  Unhealthy 108s (x2 over 112s)   kubelet, Readiness probe failed: Get "http://*****(IP but private)/healthz/ready": dial tcp *****(IP private): connect: connection refused

What I am trying to do is replacing a part of the (val) string with another string (poz). I just need to add the tag before and after the %REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)% command operator so I thought just replacing would be fine. When I try in a C++ compiler it works fine but when I try in Envoy code it gives me the above error message.

```
absl::optional<std::string> HeaderFormatter::format(const Http::HeaderMap& headers) const {
  const Http::HeaderEntry* header = findHeader(headers);
  if (!header) {
    return absl::nullopt;
  }

  std::string val = std::string(header->value().getStringView());
  truncate(val, max_length_);
  std::size_t poz = val.find("%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%"); 
  std::string val_find = "%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%";
  std::string shtesa = "[tag]%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%[/tag]";

  if ( 0 <= poz < val.length()) {

    val.replace(poz, 21, shtesa);
    return val;
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment.  Are you sure that the  kubelet is configured properly?  Have you been able to get other code to connect

Comment: Yes I am sure that the environment is working properly since I have used it several times. I am using Kubernetes version is 1.21.0 and Istio version 1.11.

Comment: What is this part supposed to do: `0 <= poz < val.length()`

Comment: I was not sure if %REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)% was part of val (string) so I wanted to be sure that the changes are happening in case %REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)% is there

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `0 <= poz && poz < val.length()`